# show confirm-dialog when press ESC key for close dialog primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, dialog

i have a dialog, if i press `ESC` key, i want show dialog confirm (Are you sure?) this event will trigger `p:commandButton`. code bellow:

```
<p:dialog id="dlgEdit" closeOnEscape="false" closable="false" modal="true">
   ...
   ...
   ...
  <p:commandButton process="@this" value="SAVE" widgetVar="btnSaveDialogEdit">
    <p:confirm ...
               message="do you want save?"/>
  </p:commandButton>

  <p:commandButton process="@this" value="CLOSE" widgetVar="btnCloseDialogEdit">
    <p:confirm ...
               message="do you want close?"/>
  </p:commandButton>

  <p:confirmDialog>
  ...two commandbutton Yes/No
  <p:confirmDialog>

  <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('btnCloseDialogEdit').getJQ().click()" />
</p:dialog>
```

when i click button `SAVE`, dialog `do you want save?` show, as soon as i press `ESC` key second dialog `do you want close` show. in the confirmdialog, enable `closeOnEscape = "true"`. i want, when i press key `ESC` on dialog `do you want save?`, this dialog will be hidden, but i can't.!!

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that by following stucture:

```
<p:dialog id="dlgEdit" widgetVar="dlgEdit"
    closeOnEscape="true" closable="false" modal="true">
    ...
    ...
    ...

    <p:confirmDialog message="Do you want to save?" widgetVar="confirmClose">
        <p:commandButton value="Yes"
            oncomplete="PF('confirmClose').hide();PF('dlgEdit').hide();" />
        <p:commandButton value="No" type="button"
            onclick="PF('confirmClose').hide();PF('dlgEdit').hide();" />
    </p:confirmDialog>

    <p:hotkey bind="esc" handler="PF('confirmClose').show();" />
</p:dialog>
```

Remember to add your `listener` for `Yes` button to handle the saving mechanism.